# Regex to remove nested double-quotes?

Tags: regex

How would I parse out the text in a string with a variable number of enclosing double-quotes?

For example, I might encounter this string:

```
"""The Cellar """"Serene"""" 16-Piece Glassware Set"""
```

or this string, etc...:

```
""The Cellar """Serene""" 16-Piece Glassware Set""
```

and I'd want to display this string:

```
The Cellar "Serene" 16-Piece Glassware Set
```

It seems regex would be an ideal solution here because there is a pattern. In all cases, the first n double-quotes defines the pattern. I want to output the balance of the string.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: Why are there four quotes after `Serene` in the second example? Typo?

Comment: I can't understand your **pattern**!..Can you explain it a bit more

Comment: Many thanks. As to language, ideally I could use Apache Hive (part of the Hadoop ecosystem), which supports regex. As to the pattern... in the above example, the first n double-quotes define the pattern. In example 1, there are 3, so everywhere we see three quotes, they should be removed. In example 2, there are two, so everywhere we see two (working outside-in), they should be removed.  I also just edited example 2, as I did not remove the last quote (sorry).

Comment: I could also stream the strings through Python, where I have a little more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could provide more details on the language you're using it would help with any regex flavor specifics. I've provided a small recursive function to solve your problem in javascript.

```
var string = '"""The Cellar """"Serene"""" 16-Piece Glassware Set"""';
var result;
function removeExcessQuotes(str)
{
    var match = str.replace('""', '"');
    result = match;
    if(match.indexOf('""') != -1)
    {
        result = match;
        removeExcessQuotes(match);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(removeExcessQuotes(string));
```

Comment: John, many thanks. I am hoping to use Apache Hive for the language and also remove the outer quotes.

Comment: But I could also stream through Python. It's an extra step, but I could definitely adapt your example if I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code will vary based on the programming language you are using (PHP, Perl, JavaScript, etc.), but the logic and regex are going to be the same. Search for `"{2,}`. That sets your pattern, so get the length of the matching string. Then do the replace by searching for `"{n}` and replacing with an empty string, where `n` is the length of the first match.

Comment: Ed, This is right on track. Ideally, I could use Apache Hive, which is Hadoop's SQL-like interface to Hadoop (it supports regex). I can test the first 10 chars of the string to count the occurrences to set the n. The only question I have with this example is whether there is a way to work outside-in. So above when I set n to 3 for example 1, I also get the instance of 4. Is there a way to limit it to 3, for example, and only take the 3 working outside in? So that would leave "Serene" in example 1.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Hadoop, but as I understand the question, you initially just want to get the length of the first match (3, in example 1). If you do a global replace -- replace all strings of `"""` with an empty string -- then `"""` is replaced with nothing and `""""` turns into `"`, which I believe is what you are shooting for. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
str="\"\"\"The Cellar \"\"\"\"Serene\"\"\"\" 16-Piece Glassware Set\"\"\"";
replace_regexp=new RegExp(str.match(/"*/)[0], "g");
str=str.replace(replace_regexp, '');
console.log(str);
```

O/P

```
The Cellar "Serene" 16-Piece Glassware Set
```

N.B. this code basically retrieves the no of `"` at the beginning of the string `str` and then removes the equal no of `"` throughout the string recursively.